# I tried installing python 3.6 in ubuntu but every time I give the command in the terminal it shows an error:

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, python-3.6

I tried installing python 3.6 in ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

It gives the following error

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux operating system ( Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035686/linux-operating-system-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

This happens lock is placed when an apt process is running, and is removed when the process completes. If there is a lock with no process running, this may mean the process got stuck for some reason and has not released the lock.

Try this:

```
ps aux | grep apt
sudo kill -9 processnumber
```

You can find more solutions on how to remove the lock here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

Then install python3.6 using this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get

Comment: again it gave an errorE: Unable to locate package python3.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6'

Comment: Follow the 2nd link in my answer and try installing. This is happening as python3.6 is not available in the universal repository for your os version. You need to add a third party repo and download from it. Link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get